# Typeahead not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, typeahead.js

I am creating a simple application to learn how to use typeahead but for some reason it is not working, an input box is displayed but cannot see the search working, I type eng but nothing is displayed and cannot figure out why. Tested in both Chrome 35 and Firefox 30. I must be doing something stupid but cannot figure out what it is.

I am getting a 200 success on the libraries and stylesheets that have been included, so no problems there.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title></title>
<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script  type="text/javascript" src="js/lib/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script  type="text/javascript" src="js/lib/typeahead.jquery.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<input id="search"/>
</body>
<script>
var countries = ["england", "ireland", "scotland", "wales"];

$('#search').typeahead({source: countries});
console.log(countries);
</script>
```

Comment: What is the default number of characters set at before the typeahead will display? Are u including the relevant css for the typeahead to display? Check your network console to see if the actual service response comes back... will help you determine the nature of the problem

Comment: the script tag should be within your `body`

Comment: Check the [docs](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/master/doc/jquery_typeahead.md#jquerytypeaheadoptions-datasets).  Your dataset is supposed to be the 2nd param.  The 1st is `options`.  Also, `source` is supposed to be a function, not an array.

Comment: I did try $('#search').typeahead(null, { source: countries}); with no luck :( The example up here: https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/ seems to send source as an array. The script tags within the body never made a difference. I'm using WebStorm and its usually quite good at complaining if there are any errors.

Comment: Brian - I have only included bootstrap.css, is there another as I downloaded the libraries from: https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js as wanted to try out BloodHound but there aren't any additional CSS libraries. I am getting 200 back from each of the libraries that are coming back. Thanks all for responding.

Comment: I never set a default number of characters but the following did not make a difference: 
            $('#search').typeahead( {hint: true,
            highlight: true,
            minLength: 1 }, { source: countries});

Comment: Rocket - I was a numpty I should have read the docs :( You were correct it requires a function

Comment: @sam: You might have been thinking of another plugin.  I think jQuery UI's supports passing it an array :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. I think it is what you are looking for. **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8aM7x/)**

```
$(function () {
    var substringMatcher = function (strs) {
        return function findMatches(q, cb) {
            var matches, substringRegex;

            // an array that will be populated with substring matches
            matches = [];

            // regex used to determine if a string contains the substring `q`
            substrRegex = new RegExp(q, 'i');

            // iterate through the pool of strings and for any string that
            // contains the substring `q`, add it to the `matches` array
            $.each(strs, function (i, str) {
                if (substrRegex.test(str)) {
                    // the typeahead jQuery plugin expects suggestions to a
                    // JavaScript object, refer to typeahead docs for more info
                    matches.push({
                        value: str
                    });
                }
            });

            cb(matches);
        };
    };

    var countries = ["england", "ireland", "scotland", "wales"];

    $('#search').typeahead({
        hint: true,
        highlight: true,
        minLength: 1
    }, {
        name: 'states',
        displayKey: 'value',
        source: substringMatcher(countries)
    });
});
```